# w3school include HTML, javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I recently used w3school include html, so that i dont have to copy-paste same div to all my pages.

First, i used it for header and footer, which uses some CSS styling, and it has no problem, works perfectly.

But then, i tried to use it again for my dropdown Navbar, which include some javascript, the HTML got included fine, but the javascript that i put doesnt work ! Nothing is wrong with the javascript, it works fine when I didn't use the include HTML. Here's the code

```js
$('#leftDrop1').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#sub1').css('display') == 'block') {

    $('#sub1').hide()

  } else {
    $("#sub1").show()
  }
})

$('#leftDrop2').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#sub2').css('display') == 'block') {

    $('#sub2').hide()

  } else {
    $("#sub2").show()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script> 

<div w3-include-html="dropdown.html"></div>
```

and here's what inside the dropdown.html

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
            <ul id="dropKiri">
                <li id="leftDrop1"><a class="dropIcon"><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>Category 1</li>
                    <div id="sub1"><ul>
                        <li>Sub 1</li>
                        <li>Sub 2</li>
                        <li>Sub 3</li>
                    </ul></div>

                <li id="leftDrop2"><a class="dropIcon"></a><i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>Category 2</li>
                    <div id="sub2"><ul>
                        <li>Sub 1</li>
                        <li>Sub 2</li>
                        <li>Sub 3</li>
                    </ul></div>

                <li style="list-style-type: none;">Category 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I dont know how to put 2 html pages on snippet, i'm sorry if this is a bit confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delegate your events beacouse w3school script uses ajax and adds new items to the dom

```
$('body').on('click','#leftDrop1',function() {
  if ($('#sub1').css('display') == 'block') {

    $('#sub1').hide()

  } else {
    $("#sub1").show()
  }
})

$('body').on('click','#leftDrop2',function() {
  if ($('#sub2').css('display') == 'block') {

    $('#sub2').hide()

  } else {
    $("#sub2").show()
  }
})
```

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly, thanks for answering madalin :D (PS: i need to wait 4 more minutes to accept your answer)

Comment: Hi, just rejected an edit-suggestion to use `toggle()` instead of `hide()` and `show()`, because toggling mustn't be the best choice for being agnostic towards the actual state of visibilty of the ele. @madalin-ivascu did it the bullet-proof way :)

Comment: Hey, this solution worked for me in a similar case but I was wondering how I would apply it to the line of code: $('#subscribe-button').addClass('successful');

Answer (score 2):

Now [w3.includeHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp) from [w3.js](https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/default.asp) allows a callback after html is loaded.

```
w3.includeHTML(function() { 
  $('#leftDrop1').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#sub1').css('display') == 'block') {
      $('#sub1').hide()
    } else {
      $("#sub1").show()
    }
  })
  $('#leftDrop2').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#sub2').css('display') == 'block') {
      $('#sub2').hide()
    } else {
      $("#sub2").show()
    }
  })
});
```