# Email subscription redirect issue with w3-include-html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am testing using the w3-include-html library in order to avoid hard coding certain code blocks that are used frequently such as the menu bar, footer, contact form, etc. on a website I am working on. At first I encountered an error with the mobile menu bar that I found a solution for [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005810/w3school-include-html-javascript-not-working). I was able to change the on click event listener that I was using for `$('body').on('click','.navbar-toggle',function() {` as instructed by the solution.

The remaining problem is that at first the email subscribe field was able to avoid redirecting a blank page that would say "You have subscribed successfully." and simply show a green check mark. After using w3-include-js it now redirects to this blank page with the text. While looking through some of the js functions I found this code:

```
$('.ajax-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('.form-required').each(function() {
            var form = this;

            var formname = this.id;

var $form = $(form);

                    if($form.data('ajaxInProcess')) {
                        return;
                    };

                    $form.data('ajaxInProcess', true);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: form.action,
                        type: form.method,
                        data: $(form).serialize(),
                        success: function(response) {
                            var responseObject = {};

                            if (typeof response === 'string') {
                                responseObject = JSON.parse(response);
                            } else {
                                responseObject = response;
                            }

                            var statusText = responseObject.status;

                            if (formname == 'subscribe') {
                                $('#subscribe-button').removeClass('successful');
                            } else if (formname == 'subscribe2') {
                                $('#subscribe-button2').removeClass('successful');
                            }
```

I believe that this is the code that needs to be edited in order to get the email subscribe working again with w3-include-html. I am hoping someone here is able to help me in applying the solution above to this code that I have included. Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to delegate the submit event as well

```
$('body').on('submit','.ajax-form',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```