# w3-include-html, javascript not working for adding and removing classes to an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using w3-include-html for header and footer code but for some reason the javascript for adding a class to a div in footer when screen size is small won't work, it works if I don't do w3-include-html.

I found something but couldn't understand how to do that in my case.
Here's what i found,

[w3school include HTML, javascript not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005810/w3school-include-html-javascript-not-working)

Here's the javascript,

```
 (function($) {
var $window = $(window),
    $html = $('.footlogo_container');

function resize() {
    if ($window.width() < 600) {

        return $html.addClass('col-xs-15');

    }

    $html.removeClass('col-xs-15');
}

$window
    .resize(resize)
    .trigger('resize');
})(jQuery);
```

And this is what's in footer.html

```
<footer class="footer" style="margin-bottom: -2%;padding-top: 7%" >
<div class="footer-top ">
<div class="container" id="cont">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="footer-col col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">

    </div>
    <div class="footer-col col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">

    </div>
    <div class="footer-col col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
      </div>


    <div class=" footer-col col-md-3 col-sm-3 footlogo_container" style="cursor: pointer;background: url('logo_imageroots.png');background-size: cover;background-position: center;" onclick="location.href='index.html';">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your <nav> element ?

Comment: @Chiller It is in the header , totally different thing.